# Center of a nonabelian p group can be found by taking the intersections of centers of two suitable maximal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $P$
be a nonabelian $p$
group. Prove that there exist maximal subgroups $M$ and $N$ of $P$ such that

$$Z(P)=Z(M) \cap Z(N).$$

I found that $Z(P) \subseteq Z(M) \cap Z(N).$ I have no idea for the reverse inclusion.

Comment: You need to assume that $P$ is finite.

Comment: When you previously posted (and then deleted) this problem (bad practice, by the way! You should edit, not delete and repost), you had additional assumptions on $P$. Without them, the statement does not hold for arbitrary $M$ and $N$; poorly phrased then, poorly phrased now.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The statement does not claim that center of P can be found by taking the intersection of the centers of any two maximal subgroups.  It states that such maximal subgroups exist.

Comment: And it is badly phrased because the condition is put as an afterthought to the equation. The better way to state it would be to say "prove that there exist maximal subgroups $M$ and $N$ such that..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$P/Z(P)$ is not cyclic, so (assuming that $P$ is finite) you can choose two distinct maximal subgroups $M,N$ containing $Z(P)$ and then $Z(P) \le Z(M) \cap Z(N)$.

For the other inclusion note that $M$ and $N$ generate $P$ and they both centralize $Z(M) \cap Z(N)$.